Adding a grid to a map in R
 So I have the following code which creates a map of species occurrence data. I want to overlay and/or add a grid to the map of Xcm by Xcm which I than can use to say how much of the area has data and how much does not have occurrence data. This is my code for mapping the marine area of Oslo with the species occurrence data. Everything has crs of 4326. I am wondering if the problem stems from the geometry column written as WKT.
# Filter shp2 to include only the geometry for the county of interest
shp2_oslo \<- shp2\[shp2$FYLKESNAVN == "Oslo", \]
intersect3_oslo \<- intersect3 %\>%
filter(FYLKESNAVN == "Oslo",)


# Plot with labels

oslo_map \<- ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = shp2_oslo, color = "gray30", size = 0.2, fill = NA) +
geom_sf(data = intersect3_oslo, aes(color = occurrences), size = 1, fill = NA) +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +  # Adding color scale for points
ggtitle("Oslo") +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),  # Remove x-axis title
axis.title.y = element_blank(),  # Remove y-axis title
plot.title.position = "plot",  # Position the title centered above the plot
plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))  # Center the title text

# Here are some things I have tried to add the grid, but none of this / none of the variations on this are working the way I want. This one at least separates the WKT to two columns.

df_sf \<- intersect3_oslo %\>%
st_coordinates() %\>%
as.data.frame() %\>%
rename(longitude = X, latitude = Y) %\>%
st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

# Here is some other stuff I tried:

intersect3_oslo1 \<- intersect3_oslo %\>%
mutate(
longitude = as.numeric(str_extract(geometry, "\[-+\]?\[0-9\]+\\.?\[0-9\]*")),
latitude = as.numeric(str_extract(geometry, "\\s(\[-+\]?\[0-9\]+\\.?\[0-9\]*)$"))
)

df_sf \<- intersect3_oslo %\>%
st_coordinates() %\>%
as.data.frame() %\>%
rename(longitude = X, latitude = Y)
print(df_sf)
df_sf \<- st_as_sf(df_sf, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

grid \<- st_make_grid(df_sf, cellsize = 2000)
grid \<- st_as_sf(grid)
grid$grid_id \<- seq_along(grid)

# Perform spatial join (count points within each grid cell)
grid_with_counts \<- st_join(df_sf, grid, intersect3_oslo) %\>%
group_by(grid_id) %\>%
summarise(occurrences = n()) %\>%
ungroup()

ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = intersect3_oslo, fill = "lightblue") +
geom_sf(data = grid_with_counts, aes(fill = species_count), color = "grey") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red", name = "Species Count") +
theme_minimal()

df_sf \<- intersect3_oslo %\>%
st_coordinates() %\>%
as.data.frame() %\>%
rename(longitude = X, latitude = Y) %\>%
st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

grid \<- st_make_grid(intersect3_oslo, cellsize = 2000)
grid \<- st_as_sf(grid)
grid$grid_id \<- seq_along(grid)
grid_with_counts \<- st_join(grid, df_sf, join = st_within) %\>%
group_by(grid_id) %\>%
summarise(occurrences = n()) %\>%
ungroup()

ggplot() +
geom_sf(data = intersect3_oslo, fill = "lightblue") +
geom_sf(data = grid_with_counts, aes(fill = occurrences), color = "grey") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red", name = "Occurrences Count") +
theme_minimal()\`

# Any guidance would be much appreciated.


Could you edit your question to include reproducible data and the minimal code needed to reproduce your problem? Thanks and good luck!

you want sf::st_make_grid(, square = TRUE), at a size that makes sense to your study, clipped to your study area.  Then test which results are in which grid square.

I'm not sure what it is that you want to do, but if you want to draw the grid over the geometry, in stead of under, you can do so with a theme(), simply add
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.1),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
    panel.ontop = TRUE
  )

